# Замена backslash при сохранении url в utf8

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, pandas, utf-8

Сохраняю pandas датафрейм в json в кодировке utf8. В датафрейм есть урлы.

```
|    |   code | url                                                               |
|---:|-------:|:------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  0 |  65615 | "mediaFiles": [{                                                  |
|    |        |                 "name": "main",                                   |
|    |        |                 "path": "https://www.mycite.ru/MPL018051LG.jpg"   |
|    |        |             }, {                                                  |
|    |        |                 "name": "auxiliary",                              |
|    |        |                 "path": "https://www.mycite.ru/MPL018051_2.jpg"   |
|    |        |             }                                                     |
|    |        |         ]                                                         |
|  1 | 654863 | "mediaFiles": [{                                                  |
|    |        |                 "name": "main",                                   |
|    |        |                 "path": "https://www.mycite.ru/MPL018051LG_1.jpg" |
|    |        |             }, {                                                  |
|    |        |                 "name": "auxiliary",                              |
|    |        |                 "path": "https://www.mycite.ru/MPL018051_5.jpg"   |
|    |        |             }                                                     |
|    |        |         ]                                                         |
```

```py
with open('test.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as file:
    product_json.to_json(file,'records',force_ascii=False)
```

В файл записываются урлы, содержащие обратные слэши.

`"path": "https:\/\/www.mycite.ru\/MPL018051_3.jpg"`

Если после экспорта повторно открыть файл и попытаться сделать замену, то к результату это не приводит, и строка со ссылкой остаётся прежней

```py
with open('test.json', 'r+', encoding='utf8') as file:
    content=file.read()
    content=content.replace('\/','/')
    file.write(content)
```